# Array of options for a select input with 3 arguments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My issue must be fairly simple, I'm using filterrific and postgis in my app but I don't think you need to know these to answer my question. So for those who don't know filterrific, we can use a select input to filter data. So we need a scope first, let's say a list of cities:

```
scope :with_city_id, lambda { |city_ids|
  where(city_id: [*city_ids])
}
```

Then we pass an array of options to the select input. For a list of cities it would look like this:

```
 with_city: City.order('LOWER(name)').map { |e| [e.name, e.id] }
```

which results in an array that looks like this:

```
[["Boston", 4], ["Los Angeles", 1], ["Miami", 3], ["New York", 5], ["San Francisco", 2]]
```

So nothing really complicated. Now the problem is that I have this scope called :with_distance that checks if a course is located within a distance.

```
scope :with_distance, -> (lat, lng, distance_in_meters) {...}
```

And it has 3 arguments which is getting me a bit confused.
If I do as follows I get an error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)":

```
[['2 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 2000], ['5 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 5000], ['10 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 10000]]
```

What's the correct way of writing this list of select_options? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the error is because of `scoping` since your `with_distance` accepts 3 parameter and you were passing only 1.

I guess you might have to change this

```
[['2 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 2000], ['5 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 5000], ['10 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 10000]]
```

in such a way below options will be passed individually.

```
'2 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 2000
'5 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 5000
'10 km', current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 10000
```

Comment: I tried `[[['2 km'], [current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 2000]], [['5 km'], [current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 2000]], [['10 km'], [current_user.lng, current_user.lat, 2000]]]` But it doesn't seem right and everything is messed up